# Merge vector layers in PyQGIS: Incorrect parameter value for LAYERS

Tags: pyqgis-3

I want to merge two vector layers in PyQGIS but I have a syntax problem.
First, I import the layers:

```
PC="G:/Path/to/my/Shapefile/PU_PrincipalesCiudades.shp"
lima="G:/Path/to/my/Shapefile/PU_LimaMetropolitana.shp"

iface.addVectorLayer(PC, "Principal Cities", "ogr")
iface.addVectorLayer(lima, "Lima", "ogr")
```

Then I write the code to merge:

```
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':['PC','lima'],'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

But I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 152, in runAndLoadResults
    context=context)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 168, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Cannot run algorithm
Incorrect parameter value for LAYERS
```

I don't know how to properly write the Layers parameter values.

Comment: What about `'LAYERS': [PC, lima]`?

Comment: OR `pc_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(PC, "Principal Cities", "ogr");
lima_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(lima, "Lima", "ogr");
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':[pc_layer, lima_layer],'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})` PS: I think @GermánCarrillo answer is simpler but my answer can be an alternative

Comment: This is really weird: before posting I already tested both - @GermánCarrillo and Thomas' recommendations but didn't work. Now I tried again and both ways works. Not sure if I was doing something wrong before but in any case thank u so much.

Comment: How should be the syntax if I want to reproject the merged layer? I mean, I did this: ```cities=processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':PC,lima],'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})``` and now I'm trying to do this: ```processing.runAndLoadResults("native:reprojectlayer", {'INPUT':cities,'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32718'),'OPERATION':'+proj=pipeline +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad +step +proj=utm +zone=18 +south +ellps=WGS84','OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})``` but I get a INPUT:invalid value

Comment: Try 'INPUT':cities['OUTPUT']

Comment: @JoséRojas, regarding the original question, you can post what worked for you as an answer, so that future readers know how to deal with problems like yours. That's the way questions are properly solved in GIS.SE. After some hours you can accept your own answer, so that the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solved the question. The first one is to change `'LAYERS': ['PC', 'lima']` for `'LAYERS': [PC, lima]`.

The second one, as described by @ThomasG77, is to setting

```
pc_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(PC, "Principal Cities", "ogr")
lima_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(lima, "Lima", "ogr")
```

Then

```
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", 
{'LAYERS': [pc_layer,lima_layer],'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```